# xcode shortcut to go to next compiler error (ignoring warnings!)

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts, xcode9

I am aware that command + ' brings you to the next issue, but is there a way to bring you to the next compiler error and ignore the warnings?
(xcode 9)

Answer (score 13):

I don't think there is a way to do that, but the closest thing you could do to that is to filter the display of issues in the Issue Navigator so it only shows errors and no warnings. Do that with one click, on the icon at the bottom right of the Issue Navigator.

[image: Screenshot of the bottom of the Issue Navigator]

Once you have done that, then the up and down arrow keys navigate you within the Issue Navigator from error to error instead of issue to issue.

Answer (score 5):

To expand on auspicious99's answer, after filtering on errors in the issues pane, you can use keyboard shortcuts end to end:

1. `cmd-5` - selects the issues pane
2. `up/down arrows` - select the error you want
3. `cmd-j`, `enter` - move the focus to the editor

Answer (score 0):

go to key bindings.

```
filter = "fix all issues"
```

Answer (score -6):

In the navigator (the left-hand pane), choose the right-most icon that looks like a speech bubble. You'll see the build results, and when you click on them you'll be taken to the error.

[image]